# SSRS - How to apply group totals only to some groups?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services

**Product Data**
ProductA  1.55
ProductB  1.60
ProductC  1.70
ProductC  1.50
ProductD  1.40

**Desired Result**

```
Product Name   Price
ProductA       1.55
ProductB       1.60
ProductC       1.70
ProductC       1.50
               3.20
ProductD       1.40

Total          7.75
```

Hello,
I have a report that usually contains rows of unique products and their sales price. (For brevity here, I've only included 2 columns)

However, occasionally a product line may appear twice on the same report (in this case, ProductC). The requirements I have are to sub total the price of the duplicate product lines, but not sub total the other product lines. Obviously I can group by product name, apply a group total, but this will apply the subtotal to all the groups.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Total Row as normal then right-click the row header and set the `Row Visibility' to an expression like this

```
=CountRows() <2
```

This simply counts the rows in the group and it it's less than 2 rows the hidden property is set to True. Only groups with more than one row will have a total row displayed.

Comment: That works, thanks. The only problem is that it leaves a blank row after every single product line. Ideally I'd like it to display like my desired result above.

Comment: That should not happen if you did it correctly. It's the entire row the needs to be hidden. I did some tests and it worked as expected.

Comment: You're right. I was applying it to the total tow textbox, as opposed to the row itself. Thanks very much for your help.